# Understanding the concepts of x86 binaries and binary analysis

Tags: binary

When people say x86 binaries, do they mean a sequence of 0, 1 such as `01001100110010001010`, or do they mean actual instructions such as `jmp aa`?

When they say binary  analysis, such as https://awesomeopensource.com/projects/binary-analysis, do they mean analysis of 0-1 sequence such as `01001100110010001010`, or analysis of code like `jmp aa; mov eax, ff`?

Comment: Depends on what "people" you mean.

Comment: x86 binaries, mean executables compiled for x86 family of processors. It has a little to do with binary numerical system *per-ce*.